# Select element issue - webdriver - c#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, nunit, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting the below error while running in NUnit,

[image]

I'm finding an element and storing it in a variable, and while trying to select the element, i'm getting the error. Tried using in this way

`IWebElement fromitem = WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("from"));` but same error persists.
Is there any way i can select the element?

Note : I verified the element id with firebug, there seems to be no problem with it.

The code below,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Events;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;

namespace SeleniumTests
{
[TestFixture]  
public class Sel
{
    public static IWebDriver WebDriver;
    private String baseURL;

    [SetUp] 
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        WebDriver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
        baseURL = "http://www.x-rates.com/calculator.html";
    }

    [TearDown] 
    public void TeardownTest()
    {
        WebDriver.Quit(); 
    }

    [Test]
    public void newtest()
    {
        WebDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/");

        var fromitem = WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("from"));
        var toitem = WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("to"));

        var fromval = new SelectElement(fromitem); //Error occurs

        var toval = new SelectElement(toitem);
        fromval.SelectByText("USD - US Dollar");
        toval.SelectByText("INR - Indian Rupee");
        WebDriver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Currency Calculator")).Click();
        var curval =   WebDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span.ccOutputRslt")).GetAttribute("Value");
        var expectedValue = 61.456825;


        Thread.Sleep(900);

        Assert.AreEqual(expectedValue, curval.Trim());

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds to me like your references are messed up. Do you reference the Support library in your application? Is Copy-Local set to true? In the folder where you are launching the tests from, in the `bin` folder, are both WebDriver DLL's there?

Comment: Bin folder having Both webdriver DLLs there. Support library been referenced. Copy-Local set to true for nunit-framework reference. Now i set the Copy-Local true for webdriver references, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: @Arran - Do you want me to set Copy-Local to True for all the References including system references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SelectElement` class can only be used with actual HTML `<select>` elements. In the page you provided, the element in question is an `<input>` element, with functionality added through CSS and JavaScript to enable it to act like a drop-down list. As such, attempting to use it with the `SelectElement` class will throw an exception indicating that the element is not of the correct type.

The "File does not exist" error message is a red herring. It's only there because NUnit is trying to show you the line of source code where the exception is thrown, which is a part of the WebDriver source code. The exception thrown by that line of code should be displayed somewhere within NUnit, which should contain the appropriate informational message.